# How to do safemath with solidity 0.8.0

Tags: solidity-0.8.x

Will (a+b) work and be safe in solidity 0.8.0? Or do I have to do something like a.add(b)?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need safemath in 0.8+, prior to that version, solidity's "+" operator wouldnt check for overflows, leading to `type(uint256).max + 1 = 0`, and we'd use the safeMath library to avoid that. Now, `type(uint256).max + 1` reverts with `Panic(0x11)`, and safeMath isnt needed anymore. If you want to reproduce pre-0.8 behavior, you can put your operations inside and `unchecked{}` block, saves gas, so is recommended if you know your operation is safe already.